# Need help for windows 10 support for my NDIS 5.1 IM driver

Tags: kernel, windows-10, driver, ndis, network-driver

we are using a open source NDIS IM driver(5.1) which is working fine in windows 7 machine but when we tried in Windows 10 machine its not loading.

Driver : ipfw+dummynet

Ipfw web site : http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/
Source Code : https://github.com/luigirizzo/dummynet

Looks like NDIS 5.1 code to be migrated to NDIS 6.X or LWF to work on Windows 10.

Please suggest a solution or a workaround so that we can use this driver in Windows 10 machine,Your help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have the same issue I talked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464145/was-compatibility-for-ndis-5-x-drivers-removed-in-windows-10) and opened a Microsoft support case about.

In Windows 10, a new network class Installer called NetSetup was added with a shim for the old NetCfg calls. There's a bug in the shim that causes drivers like ours to install but not bind to any adapters. If that's the behavior you're seeing, unfortunately the result of my support case was that MS decided not to fix the problem because it affects so few people. You could open your own case, on the theory that the more reports they get the more likely they are to fix it, but you probably will have to rewrite the driver.

Comment: I think not just binding,visually also we are unable to see the driver in the network properties when we are trying to install in windows 10 machine.so the loading the driver itself failing.

Comment: OK, probably not the same problem then. But it seems that even though there is supposed to be backward compatibility for NDIS 5.x drivers in Windows 10, Microsoft is not committed to maintaining it. So you may want to rewrite the driver anyway.

Comment: Thanks Jeffm. I am able to find a solution.